# How to show results in a mysql database only if two fields in unison are not the same

Tags: mysql, where-clause, exists

### I have a mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE tipoUFRubros(
    idTipoUFRubro int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    idConsorcio int not null,
    idRubro int not null,
    idTipoUF int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### This are the table's contents:

```
=== idTipoUFRubro === idConsorcio === idRubro ==== idTipoUF
=== 75 ===============  2 =========== 1 =========== 1
=== 76 ===============  2 =========== 2 =========== 1
=== 77 ===============  2 =========== 4 =========== 1
=== 78 ===============  2 =========== 5 =========== 1
=== 79 ===============  2 =========== 6 =========== 1
=== 80 ===============  2 =========== 7 =========== 1
=== 81 ===============  2 =========== 8 =========== 1
=== 82 ===============  2 =========== 9 =========== 1
=== 83 ===============  2 =========== 1 =========== 2
=== 84 ===============  2 =========== 2 =========== 2
=== 85 ===============  2 =========== 3 =========== 2
=== 86 ===============  2 =========== 4 =========== 2
=== 87 ===============  2 =========== 5 =========== 2
=== 88 ===============  2 =========== 6 =========== 2
=== 89 ===============  2 =========== 7 =========== 2
=== 90 ===============  2 =========== 8 =========== 2
=== 91 ===============  2 =========== 9 =========== 2
=== 92 ===============  2 =========== 1 =========== 3
=== 93 ===============  2 =========== 2 =========== 3
=== 94 ===============  2 =========== 4 =========== 3
=== 95 ===============  2 =========== 5 =========== 3
=== 96 ===============  2 =========== 6 =========== 3
=== 97 ===============  2 =========== 7 =========== 3
=== 98 ===============  2 =========== 8 =========== 3
=== 99 ===============  2 =========== 9 =========== 3
=== 100 ==============  2 =========== 10 ========== 3
```

### What I want to achieve:

I'm trying to get all the rows that have a specific `idRubro` and `idTipoUF` (last two columns) but not if the `idRubro` is already appearing with a different `idTipoUF`.

Example:
I want to get the `idRubro` 1 only if `idTipoUF` is 1, but there are no `idRubro` 1 with `idTipoUF` 2 or 3. So I want to list all idRubros that are ONLY associated to idTipoUF 1.

If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM tipoUFRubros 
WHERE idRubro = 1
AND idTipoUF = 1
AND idTipoUF != 2
```

I do get the result of `idRubro` 1, even if there is an `idTipoUF` 2 that shares `idRubro` 1 as well.

What can I do? I've unsuccessfully tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tipoUFRubros 
WHERE idRubro = 1
(AND idTipoUF = 1 AND idTipoUF != 2)
```

Which of course dos not work.

**I need a comparison where I check for a pair not to exist. How do I do that?**

Comment: I'm surprised that you accepted (and upvoted?) a wrong answer. Check it here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tZ1KA1tSkQnQrKZmScyqeN/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with EXISTS if a special combination exists or not in your case

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM tipoUFRubros
> WHERE idRubro = 1
> AND idTipoUF = 1
> AND NOT EXISTS (
>     SELECT *
>     FROM tipoUFRubros
>     WHERE idRubro = 1
>     AND idTipoUF = 2
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> idTipoUFRubro | idConsorcio | idRubro | idTipoUF
> ------------: | ----------: | ------: | -------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d81eb55c78b23c0fdd4db374eb1a450)*

Comment: This query can never return anything. The `NOT EXISTS` condition filters out everything selected by `AND idTipoUF = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to check for rows with a different `idTipoUF`

```
SELECT *
FROM tipoUFRibros
WHERE idRubro = 1
AND idTipoUF = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tipoUFRibros
    WHERE idRibro = 1
    AND idTipoUF != 1
)
```

Comment: @Rosamunda Why did you edit my answer? This query can never return anything. The main query selects rows with `idTipoUF = 1`, but the subquery will exclude them.